# Why are the parameters in the constructors for ArgumentNullException and ArgumentException reversed?

Tags: c#, .net

When designing software, I've always favoured consistency unless there is a *really* good reason to be inconsistent.

In the .NET Framework, we have the [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which both derive from `ArgumentException`. All 3 of these have a constructor that accepts two string parameters - one for the `paramName` and one for the exception `message`.

Why do both of the derived classes reverse the parameter order?!

```
public ArgumentNullException(String paramName, String message)
    : base(message, paramName) { }

public ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String paramName, String message)
    : base(message, paramName) { }
```

Which means in my calling code, it'd look something like this:

```
public string DoSomething(string name, int age)
{
    if (name == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name", "Name cannot be null.");

    if (name == string.Empty)
        throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be an empty string.", "name");

    if (age < 18)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("age", "Age must be at least 18.");

    //Do stuff
}
```

To me, this seems really illogical and often confuses me. Is there any reason at all for this design choice by Microsoft here? Are there any advantages to the reversed order when using these two derived exceptions?

Comment: I suspect the authos of `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` prefered the param/message order and were not in a position to change the order of `ArgumentException`

Comment: Perhaps someone at Microsoft screwed it up, and the code reviewers missed it?..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the constructor which takes only one argument, takes a *different* argument:

`ArgumentNullException(String)` takes `paramName` as argument, `ArgumentException(String)` takes a `message`.

This is actually very consistent this way. The two-string constructor just adds an argument, keeping the first one identical.

The reasoning behind it, is problably because `ArgumentNullException` doesn't need a message. The message is inherent in the exception type.

Comment: I spotted that, but then that raises the question: Why is the single parameter version the `paramName` for the two, but `message` for the base class? Even more confusion!!

Comment: @ConnellWatkins I think because the message can be understood from the exception type (I updated my answer).

Comment: Consistent in one way, horrendous in all other ways. Principle of least astonishment is not an Exception, but it is a Human Error.